# Why TraceV in ATL/MFC will cause memory leak?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks, mfc, atl

I am using VS2019, the C++ code is compiled to 32 bit exe binary. The OS is Windows 10.

The TraceV is located in MSVC\14.24.283\atlmfc\include\atltrace.h.

It internally uses the following code to allocate a char or wchar_t array to hold the trace string.

```
        CHeapPtr<wchar_t> wszBuf;
        if (!wszBuf.Allocate(chCount))
        {
            return;
        }

        wszBuf[0] = '\0';

        if (swprintf_s(wszBuf, chCount, L"%ls%ls", wszCategory, pwszMessage) == -1)
        {
            return;
        }
```

If you look into CHeapPtr, the memory will be Freed in destructor. There seems to have no reason to leak any memory here.

In Release mode, there's no memory leak (I tried to monitor in task manager and the memory is not increasing too much for a very long time).

In Debug mode, the memory used soon reaches 2G and it causes memory allocation exception.

I tried to use _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(), and to my surprise, the memory leaks are all small objects with 10-50 bytes and they should be created in TraceV function. However, since there are so many traces, from the memory leak dump I cannot identify which Trace call causes memory leak and therefore it is hard to debug and step to see why it's not freed.

For those who suspect that the leak is not from TraceV's CHeapPtr Allocate, there's a snapshot below. As you can see, I took the snapshot at 14 seconds after the application started, and there are a lot of char[] and wchar_t[] around with age more than 7 seconds, and those char[] and wchar_t[] are allocated in TraceV, which means they are not deallocated in 7 seconds! And the 7 seconds number will keep increase with time goes by.

[image: Snapshot of memory]

Is there any hints on this?

Thanks.

Comment: The code posted doesn't leak memory. If there is indeed a leak, the leak is somewhere else, in code we cannot see. Please provide a [mcve]. As for Release configurations: By default, as long as you use the public interface, the ATL tracing facilities aren't compiled into the executable. They compile down to no-ops by way of conditional compilation.

Comment: `TRACE` doesn't leak memory. `CHeapPtr` has automatic cleanup. If you make a minimum MFC hello world program with `TRACE`, you will not find leaks. You haven't shown your usage of `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks`, it must be wrong.

Comment: As close as you can get to a sure thing, this is your leak. I've caused leaks to show in the MS libs plenty of times, always my fault. I've got one right now that: d:\agent\_work\3\s\src\vctools\VC7Libs\Ship\ATLMFC\Src\MFC\tooltip.cpp(479) : {101926} normal block at 0x0055CD80, 48 bytes long.
It is my leak, I just haven't bothered to hunt it down yet.